# Displaying entries in a database live

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

So I was checking out this tutorial: [the tutorial](http://tutorialsbay.com/python-tkinter-sqlite3-gui/). The code doesn't run, it has some errors, but I was able to fix those. What I'm wondering how to do is use tkinter, and mysqlite3 to lively update a list of entries. So let's say I insert an entry, it will within a second or two be displayed onto the list. In this tutorial, this is done by clicking "Show Notes".

What I am asking is how do you create a lively updated list of entries from a database using Tkinter, and Python?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @MikeW I have edited the question to make what I'm asking more clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually can't look at the source material, so this could be completely wrong in which case I'll delete. How about you use a `Thread` to keep calling that Show Notes function every couple seconds? Something like....

```
import threading #if you haven't already, as I said I can't look at your link atm

def show_notes(*args,**kwargs):
    # whatever you already have implemented here that that button calls

class Update(threading.Thread):
    from time import sleep
    daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            show_notes()
            sleep(2)

tick = Update()
tick.start()
```

This is an ugly implementation, since basically you're asking for a full dump of your SQL Server every two seconds, but it WILL do what you want it to for very small databases. If you've got anything bigger than that, you may want to change the way you're adding notes so to put them in a `Queue` as a change, then have your `ListBox` run through the `Queue` and pull each new commit individually from the server.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Python, so haven't quite heard of threads. I will try this, let you know if I get it going.

Comment: @tyler5819 please be advised of the note I just added at the end. This is a terrible way to implement this, but for smallish datasets it will function. Basically it's requesting a dump of your SQL Server every two seconds, which is a Bad Thing for anything non-trivial.

Comment: Keep in mind also that this tutorial is 2 years old, and some of the methods they suggest using are now Old and Buster and have been replaced by New Hotness.

Comment: So I'm getting an error: "NameError: global name 'show_notes' is not defined". Would this be because I already have another class called 'Program', that holds the def 'show_notes'?

Comment: Also, there would never be more then 10 entries at a time anyways.

Comment: Yes, change `show_notes` to `application.show_notes()`